# assembly binding logging is turned off

Tags: .net

im trying to run a web appilication in .net framework...
and got error.. help me to resolve..
thanks in advance...

### Server Error in '/PSS.NET' Application.

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

Line 21:        
Line 22:            
Line 23:                
Line 24:                
Line 25:

Source File: D:\ISSM\Dynamic\Code\PSSFinalSQL\PSS.NET\web.config    Line: 23

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.1433; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.1433

Answer (score 0):

Is the Crystal Reports runtime installed on the server?

http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp

Comment: Hi i have installed Crystal report basic runtime for visual studio 2008...
still have a problem..
Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: It is particular about the version. It can't be lower or higher. Unfortunately, I don't know which version of the run time you need to install in order to get version 11.5.3300.0. I suspect it is one of the 'XI' ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
Go to this ----
cmd------------->migrator.exe.config

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>

replace this code to below code

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration> 
<startup>
<requiredRuntime version="v4.0.20506" safemode="true"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```